# Jira SSO bypass login page

Tags: single-sign-on, jira, saml

I'm running jira server behind an IBM http server, I'm trying to implement the web SSO with saml in the IHS level, everything works fine but, the problem here is that I'm redirected automatically to the Jira login page.

Have you any idea how to bypass the authentication in jira( the user is already authenticated in the web server)

Regards

Answer (score 1):

https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/bypass-saml-authentication-for-jira-data-center-869009810.html may be some help, You enable the bypass and then use a URL such as <BASE_URL>/login.jsp?auth_fallback